# passing array from view using ajax to another view codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Code segments of my application are added below. `myArray` is an array and each element contains few objects. I need to use that array in 2nd view.

When I `alert(myJSON);` getting the array in alert window. When the view loads it displays `NULL`.

**Ajax call on my first view**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btn-click").click(function(){

    var tmp = myArray;
    var details= JSON.stringify(tmp);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/Application1/index.php/Welcome/loadDetails',
        data: {details: details},
        success : function(myJSON){
            alert(myJSON);
            console.log('Posted');
            location.href="http://localhost/Application1/index.php/Welcome/loadDetails"

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });    
 });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function loadDetails()
{
            $data = [];
            $data['load_details'] = $this->input->post('details');
    $this->load->view('load_view',$data);
}
```

**2nd View**

```
var_dump($load_details);
```

What are the changes that I should do to display passed arary in my 2nd view.

Comment: its not clear what you exactly want ? . Are you trying to load your view with ajax after the posting the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get data in 2nd view then you need to call ajax one more time in success instead of location.href .(Using location.href, you will not get data in loadDetails() method . )

Try with this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/Application1/index.php/Welcome/loadDetails',
        data: {details: details},
        success : function(myJSON){
            alert(myJSON);
            console.log('Posted');
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost/Application1/index.php/Welcome/loadDetails',
                data: {details: details},
                success : function(mydata){
                    alert(mydata);
                }
            }); 
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
```